# Stuck in creating a room while implementing chat using SocketIO

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I am using EJS, socket.io, express, nodejs to implement live chat.

First of all, I'm using a Class instance instead of Redis or MongoDB because it's a simple local test.

The problems of the current project are as follows.

When the user presses the chat join button, the page should be redirected and the screen should change.

But in the code I wrote
If you look at the `Route.js` page
io.emit('create_room', req.body.room) is not passed

If you record io to console.log, the properties are normally output.

Not when sending data.

How to solve it?

`app.js`

```js
import express from 'express';
import { createServer } from 'http';
import { Server, Socket } from 'socket.io';
import https from 'https';
import path from 'path';
import mainRouter from './bin/core/routes/main/mainRoute.js';
import boardRouter from './bin/core/routes/board/boardRoute.js';
import methodOverride from 'method-override';
import liveRouter from './bin/core/routes/chat/liveChatRoute.js';
import liveChatConroller from './bin/core/controller/liveChatController.js';

let port = process.env.SPORT || 8080;

const __dirname = path.resolve();

let app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use('/static', express.static(`${__dirname}/bin/core` + '/static'));

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(methodOverride('_method'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(`${__dirname}/bin/core`, 'views/'));

app.use(mainRouter);
app.use('/livechat', liveRouter);

const httpServer = createServer(app).listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Success! *:${port}`);
});
const ws = new Server(httpServer);
app.set('socketIO', ws);

ws.on('connection', (socket) => {
  app.set('socketClients', socket);
  app.set('socketid', socket.id);

  console.log('Client Socket id', socket.id);
  liveChatConroller(ws, socket);
});

export default app;
```

`liveChatRouter.js`

```js
import express from 'express';
import {
  rooms,
  users,
} from '../../../utils/[Class]livechatData/newInstance.js';

const chatRouter = express.Router();

console.log(rooms.rooms);
console.log(users.users);

chatRouter.get('/', (req, res) => {
  let io = req.app.get('socketIO');
  let socket = req.app.get('socketClients');

  res.render('liveChat/liveChatMain.ejs', {
    title: 'RTC Chat App',
    userlist: users.users,
    roomlist: rooms.rooms,
  });

  io.on('update_user_list', (data) => {
    console.log('incoming Data', data);
  });
});

// chatRouter.post('/user', (req, res) => {
//   console.log(req.body);
//   let io = req.app.get('socketIO');
//   let socket = req.app.get('socketClients');
//   let socketid = req.app.get('socketid');
//   console.log(socketid);
//   res.redirect(`/livechat/`);
//   io.emit('join_user', { username: req.body.user });
//   io.to(socketid).emit('join_user', { username: req.body.user });
//   socket.emit('join_user', { username: req.body.user });
// });

chatRouter.post('/room', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Room Title' + req.body.room);
  let io = req.app.get('socketIO');
  let socket = req.app.get('socketClients');
  res.redirect(`/livechat/${req.body.room}`);

  io.emit('create_room', { roomname: req.body.room });
});

chatRouter.get('/:room', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params);
  console.log(req.path);
  // res.render('liveChat/liveChatRoom.ejs', {
  //   room: req.params.room,
  // });
});
```

`liveChatController.js`

```js
import { rooms, users } from '../../utils/[Class]livechatData/newInstance.js';

const liveChatConroller = (ws, socket) => {

  socket.on('join_user', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    if (data.username) {
      if (users.isExists(data.username)) {
        console.log('exist username');
      } else {
        let user = users.addUser(socket.id, data.username);
        console.log('user', user);

        ws.emit('update_user_list', user);
      }
    }
  });

  socket.on('create_room', (room) => {
    let roomid = rooms.rooms.length;
    let roomname = room.roomname;
    
    let owner = users.getCurrentUserId(room.currentUser);
  
    if (roomname && owner) {
      let roomdata = rooms.addRoom(roomid, roomname, owner.spec.username);

      console.log(roomdata.info.rname);
      console.log(roomdata);
      socket.leave(socket.room);
      socket.join(socket.room);
      socket.room = roomname;
    }
  });

  socket.on('join_room', (room) => {
    console.log('JoinedRoom', room);
    socket.leave(socket.room);
    socket.room = room;
    socket.join(socket.room);
  });
```

Comment: Try to focus on one question at once. It will be easier for anyone to help you and others with the same (focussed) question might benefit from the answers provided.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier
Looking at it again, the article is a mess. We'll fix it right away.